# Activiti integration in ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, activiti, apache-servicemix

I don't find any clue to change Activiti 5.16.1 database parameter in ServiceMix.

Source example is exemples/activiti/activiti-camel  in ServiceMix 5.1.0

By default Activiti work with h2 database. I want it to work with Postgresql.

First I have installed PostgreSQL JDBC Driver OSGi bundle (9.1.901.jdbc4_1).

Second, following Activiti's user guide I've placed a activiti.cfg.xml in exemple classpath (resources and resources/OSGI-INF).

activiti.cfg.xml :

`<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti" />
<property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
<property name="jdbcUsername" value="activiti" />
<property name="jdbcPassword" value="activiti" />`

H2 is always still used.

I've tried many other options includind buildind "activiti-config" ServiceMix subproject but it always fails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no direct way to change the configuration of the H2 database. You can refer to the following question, [Servicemix Camel Activiti Integration and H2 Database configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902092/servicemix-camel-activiti-integration-and-h2-database-configuration)