# Servicemix Camel Activiti Integration and H2 Database configuration

Tags: apache-camel, activiti, apache-servicemix, fuseesb, jboss-esb

I have configured Activiti on Servicemix 5.1.1 and got it working with Camel. I need to configure Activiti to use SQL Server instead of the default inbuilt H2 which comes with servicemix for Activiti during feature installation. I am not finding any config files related to activiti to change the DB credentials either.

Any help on how to configure the Activiti DB with Servicemix is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to configuring another database at the moment. The solution would be to create a Blueprint XML file like the one we're using internally (cfr. https://github.com/apache/servicemix/blob/master/activiti/activiti-config/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/activiti-config.xml - you may have to remove the custom resolver bits), modify it to point to your SQL server and drop it in ServiceMix' `deploy` directory.

FWIW, I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SM-2379 to provide a more convenient way to define a new database.

Comment: Thanks, Gert for the clarification and the Jira ticket